# Alternative way to enforce foreign key constraint using spring boot and hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, foreign-keys

Is there any alternative ways to enforce foreign key constraints with JPA, Hibernate, etc. to minimize to data stored against a POJO?

I have a spring boot project with User and Form Model, Dao, and Controller classes that is connected to a MySQL database. A User can have many Forms but a Form can only have one User. So the relationship is one to many. To enforce the foreign key constraint I use the @OneToMany annotation with a List. With this design, when I use an HTTP GET method in postman, a single user returns the user AND all his/her associated forms, which I don't like. Is there another way to enforce the a foreign key constraint such that I don't have to store all the information against the User class, but ensure referential integrity within the database?

Below is my User Class. At the bottom is where I create a List of type Form and annotate it with the @OneToMany annotation and then tell it which attribute in the form class to join it with using the @JoinColumn

```java
package org.hoa.HOA_Website.WebsiteDatabaseAPI.Entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import java.util.List;


@Entity
@Table
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long userID;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(length = 30)
    private String middleName;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(length = 14)
    private String phoneNumber;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(length = 50, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean admin;

    private int age;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String passwordHash;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Form.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "submitter_id")
    private List<Form> formsMade;
/*
Getters and Setters Below
*/
```

Now below here is the Form Class. Above submitter I have the column named such that it will match the @JoinColumn annotation. This ensures that all submitter ids sent via a POST method having a matching user id.

```java
package org.hoa.HOA_Website.WebsiteDatabaseAPI.Entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table
public class Form {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long formID;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date dateSubmitted;

    @Column(name = "submitter_id", nullable = false)
    private Long submitter;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean approvalStatus;

    @Column(length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String formType;
/*
Getters and Setters Below
*/
```

BUT, when i perform a GET method to find all the Users. I get all the Users AND their associated Forms.

```
[
    {
        "userID": 1,
        "firstName": "Jane",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "middleName": "Halyard",
        "phoneNumber": "1234567890",
        "email": "janedoe@gmail.com",
        "admin": false,
        "age": 20,
        "passwordHash": "klsjfougalsdg2e98y54e982ajsdng924uierg",
        "formsMade": [
            {
                "formID": 5,
                "dateSubmitted": "2019-06-11T12:25:43.000+0000",
                "submitter": 1,
                "approvalStatus": false,
                "formType": "ConstructionForm"
            },
            {
                "formID": 6,
                "dateSubmitted": "2019-06-11T12:25:43.000+0000",
                "submitter": 1,
                "approvalStatus": false,
                "formType": "HardshipForm"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "userID": 2,
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "middleName": "Michael",
        "phoneNumber": "0987654321",
        "email": "johndoe@gmail.com",
        "admin": true,
        "age": 32,
        "passwordHash": "klsjfougalsdg2e98y5423bt49sdgajsdng924uierg",
        "formsMade": [
            {
                "formID": 3,
                "dateSubmitted": "2019-06-11T12:25:43.000+0000",
                "submitter": 2,
                "approvalStatus": false,
                "formType": "HardshipForm"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

So finally, is there anyway to ensure referential integrity but without storing so much on the User? Hopefully more like relational data structures and just store the foreign key on the Form?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are after is a [**DTO**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object).

> Is there any alternative ways to enforce foreign key constraints with JPA, Hibernate, etc. to minimize to data stored against a POJO?

Discussing about a [**POJO**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object) is a bit inaccurate. Your **Entities** define [**ORM**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) and those should be defined as they are. You should think about what is the data you return. Your entiteis do not actually *store the data* but you populate them with all the data and return all that data if you query and return them as they are, so using them also as DTOs.

It seems that you return `Collection<User>` (so entities) as a response.

Instead you should return a collection of DTOs - say - `Collection<SimpleUserDTO>` where DTO could be like:

```
public class SimpleUserDTO {
    public Long userID;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String middleName;
    public String phoneNumber;
    public String email;
    public Boolean admin;
    public int age;
    public String passwordHash;
    // NOTE: no formsMade here!
}
```

So your **Controller** method should call **Service** method that returns this collection of DTOs that it obtains from some `Repository` method either already **mapped** as DTOs or as entities that Service method then maps one by one to be a DTO.

In your Service method you could map entity values to DTO - field by field or perhaps with a library like [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/) - but best way in my opinion would be that you implemented a **Repository** method ( with a **Projection** or a **Tuple** query) that populates this DTO straight from the query and lets the Service method call that.

And after all this very ugly but easy way to achive this same would just loop the users in your Controller and set the `formsMade` to `null` but it is finally a very inefficient solutions and will not be a flexible way to hanled all this conversion stuff later with different results etc...

There is a lot of stuff to explain more in details but I hope that with this information you might be able to find more information from SO or elsewhere in relevant documentation.

And: of course you need to map back from DTO to entity then when passing data to Controller.

Comment: You're right I shouldn't be referring to it as a POJO. DTO is the correct terminology. The DTOs are stored in their respective DAOs which extend JPARepository. This I believe provides the service methods that my controller calls. So are you saying ModelMapper could enforce the foreign key constraint I desire and then I could return User like you did with SimpleUserDTO?

Comment: That anyway means the GET users query is still to fetch all the forms as well. The only difference is that forms won't be display. I would remove `@OneToMany` from user entity and moved it to the Form entity in a way like `@ManyToOne`

Comment: @JosephMalecki All the ORM side stuff like FKs should be in your entities. Model mapper or any mapper/mapping stuff just picks the needed stuff to DTO and back, nothing more. It could be anything that is mapped not only Entity so not necessarily JPA/ORM related. Usually good practise is to have Controller<>Service<>Repository layers in your Spring app so liek taht you have a separate Service class for example annotated with `@Service`.

Comment: @SergVasylchak ```@ManyToOne``` was another implementation I was considering as well. But for some I couldn't get it to work. Would you be willing to provide an answer with how you'd implement the ```@ManyToOne``` annotation in such a use case?

Comment: @JosephMalecki `@ManyToOne` on the Form side would definitely work but it also requires removing List formsMade from the User side if you want to prevent Forms to propagate to response. Then you would need to access Forms some other way than User.getFormsMade elsewhere in the code I think.

Comment: @pirho So I was also considering bringing that up to my team lead as well. Want if I wanted to maximize information on the DTOs and have ```@ManyToOne``` on the Form side and also have ```@OneToMany``` on the User side to have as much information readily available as possible. But your saying that can't be done? I can only use one of the two?

Comment: @JosephMalecki I am not saying that. You can use both and have a bidirectional mapping. I am saying that if you use Entity itself as a DTO and it has the list formsMade then formsMade will be in the response.